# Thymeleaf doesn't bind Spring's ModelAndView

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a Controller like this:

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

@Autowired
private SomeService someService;

@RequestMapping("/")
public ModelAndView index() {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("index");
    mav.addObject("title", someService.getTitle());
    mav.addObject("text", someService.getText());
    return mav;
}
```

}

Now thymeleaf is supposed to have some knowledge about the mav:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head lang="de">

    <title>${title}</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>${title}</h1>
    <h2>${text}</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

But in my frontend it doesn't work and outputs the template vars:

```
${title}

${text}
```

Any ideas? Am I missing some configuration about the ViewResolver in Spring?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head lang="de">

    <title th:text="${title}"></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 th:text="${title}"></h1>
    <h2 th:text="${text}">My Dummy Data</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a 4 year old question, and Stefano's answer is correct. But this is also correct (inlining):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head lang="de">

    <title>${title}</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>[[${title}]]</h1>
    <h2>[[${text}]]</h2>
</body>
</html>
```